# How to run a BAT in one VM using C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, virtual-machine

I have a VM that I need to run a BAT from another computer.

In my computer, I have this code:

```
string dir = "\\\\10.0.0.0\\C$\\KillWatcher.bat";

while (!System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dir).HasExited) ;
```

But when I execute that, it runs on my pc, not in the VM. 
Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: I don't know how you can do this in C#, but PsExec (from Microsoft) allows you to remotely execute stuff.

Comment: PowerShell Remoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7

Comment: Do you care if it runs on local machine or remote machine?  You just want to make sure the relative paths for input/output are correct.  So if you did a cd before running would that work?

Comment: "PowerShell Remoting learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/… – David Browne - Microsoft"

I'm trying that, but how can I run in my code?? Can I call my vm's powershell and put the command to exec the bat?? 
First of all, Powershell can't run a bat file, it only exec a ps1 kind of file, and I can't change the bat because of another process. So how can I do that?

Comment: "Do you care if it runs on local machine or remote machine? You just want to make sure the relative paths for input/output are correct. So if you did a cd before running would that work?" Yes, I care... My bat file kill a process on VM, so this bat has to execute on VM. The file is already there, but when a I call it executes the command on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that by opening the System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create().AddCommand(). This is enought to open the VM and execute the BAT file.

The code is like this:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

ps.AddCommand(dirDestino);

ps.AddCommand("IniciarWatcher.bat");
```